# Comic titles "impartial differential equations", "improbability", but what is "different finitenesses" supposed to be?

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, terminology, puzzle, popular-math

The following is a quote from [Naming Infinity: A True Story of Religious Mysticism and Mathematical Creativity By Loren Graham, Jean-Michel Kantor](https://books.google.com/books?id=QX5Fj6DWEqIC)

> The students were so devoted to their teachers' studies of set theory that they made fun of mathematicians who worked in other areas, giving their topics comic titles such as "impartial differential equations," "theory of improbability," and "different finitenesses."

"impartial differential equations" is for partial differential equations, and "theory of improbability," is for theory of probability, but what's "different finitenesses"?

Comment: Perhaps it is just an inversion of the "different infinities" that set theorists study.

Comment: @symplectomorphic So, the students are studying set theory but are making fun of a set theory concept?

Comment: Calculus of finite differences?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thank you!

Comment: I have heard of Category Theory referred to as Abstract Nonsense.